# Polymorphic Association with multiple associations on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm slightly confused about a polymorphic association I've got. I need an Article model to have a header image, and many images, but I want to have a single Image model. To make matters even more confusing, the Image model is polymorphic (to allow other resources to have many images).

I'm using this association in my Article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :header_image, :as => :imageable
  has_many :images, :as => :imageable
end
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: has_one is synctactic sugar for has_many :limit => 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Polymorphic Association with multiple associations on the same model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494452/rails-polymorphic-association-with-multiple-associations-on-the-same-model)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. That's totally possible.

You might need to specify the class name for `header_image`, as it can't be inferred. Include `:dependent => :destroy` too, to ensure that the images are destroyed if the article is removed

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :header_image, :as => :imageable, :class_name => 'Image', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :images, :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

then on the other end...

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Comment: I'm five years late to the party, but for future reference see [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494452/rails-polymorphic-association-with-multiple-associations-on-the-same-model).

Comment: Pease cancel this as the accepted answer. This solution does not work, see comment above by @Sooie. The real solution is in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494452/rails-polymorphic-association-with-multiple-associations-on-the-same-model

Answer (score 7):

I tried this, but then header_image returns one of the images. Simply because the images table doesn't specify a different image use type (header_image vs. normal image). It simply says: imageable_type = Image for both uses. So if there's no information stored about the use type, ActiveRecord cannot differentiate.

Comment: You need single table inheritance