# Rails polymorphic associations, two assoc types in one class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

Consider a class:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :link_votes, :as => :vote_subject, :class_name => 'Vote'
  has_many :spam_votes, :as => :vote_subject, :class_name => 'Vote'

end
```

The problem is, when I'm adding a new vote with `@link.link_votes << Vote.new` the `vote_subject_type` is `'Link'`, while I wish it could be `'link_votes'` or something like that. Is this an AR limitation or is there a way to workaround this thing?

I've actually found one related answer, but I'm not quite sure about what it says: [Polymorphic Association with multiple associations on the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168047/polymorphic-association-with-multiple-associations-on-the-same-model/1764117#1764117)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use Single Table Inheritance - this will allow you to have two different types of Votes.  This will add a 'type' column to the votes table that you will then access as a LinkVote or SpamVote

```
class SpamVote << Vote
  ...
end
```

Along those lines.

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :link_votes, :as => :vote_subject
  has_many :spam_votes, :as => :vote_subject

end
```

In the votes table you'd see columns like:

```
id, type, vote_subject_type, vote_subject_id, etc.
```

Do more research on STI and I bet you'll find your answer.