# Rails Polymorphic Association with multiple associations on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

My question is essentially the same as this one:
[Polymorphic Association with multiple associations on the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168047/polymorphic-association-with-multiple-associations-on-the-same-model)

However, the proposed/accepted solution does not work, as illustrated by a commenter later.

I have a Photo class that is used all over my app. A post can have a single photo. However, I want to re-use the polymorphic relationship to add a secondary photo.

Before:

```
class Photo 
   belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Post
   has_one :photo, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Desired:

```
class Photo 
   belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Post
   has_one :photo,           :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
   has_one :secondary_photo, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

However, this fails as it cannot find the class "SecondaryPhoto". Based on what I could tell from that other thread, I'd want to do:

```
   has_one :secondary_photo, :as => :attachable, :class_name => "Photo", :dependent => :destroy
```

Except calling Post#secondary_photo simply returns the same photo that is attached via the Photo association, e.g. Post#photo === Post#secondary_photo. Looking at the SQL, it does WHERE type = "Photo" instead of, say, "SecondaryPhoto" as I'd like...

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: This how to may also help: https://github.com/tokhi/polymorphism-in-rails/

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I have done that in my project.

The trick is that photos need a column that will be used in has_one condition to distinguish between primary and secondary photos. Pay attention to what happens in `:conditions` here.

```
has_one :photo, :as => 'attachable', 
        :conditions => {:photo_type => 'primary_photo'}, :dependent => :destroy

has_one :secondary_photo, :class_name => 'Photo', :as => 'attachable',
        :conditions => {:photo_type => 'secondary_photo'}, :dependent => :destroy
```

The beauty of this approach is that when you create photos using `@post.build_photo`, the photo_type will automatically be pre-populated with corresponding type, like 'primary_photo'. ActiveRecord is smart enough to do that.

Comment: I like the idea a lot, only problem is I can't get rails to write the correct value into the photo_type column, it's always Photo. Am I missing something, how do you get rails to write 'primary photo' into the photo_type column?

Comment: What's the name of your column? Make sure it's not just `type` since that's a special column rails uses to write the name of current class.

Comment: The above code didn't work for me. The :conditions => {:photo_type => 'primary_photo'} didn't change the photo_type column content. It was still the class of my model. What did work was add a new column to the database, photo_sub_type (string), and set my :conditions => {:photo_sub_type => 'primary_photo'} but then every association has to have the :conditions => {:photo_sub_type => [some value here]} specified. But it works just as I wanted it to. Use the same Photo model to attach many different types of photos to another model.

Comment: The above code works, BUT: The reason you're having problems, Rob, is that the above code assumes you are doing Single Table Inheritance in your model

Comment: @Houen wait, where does it assume that?

Comment: @hakunin I'm assuming you have two different types of Photo classes, say FirstPhoto and SecondaryPhoto that both derive from Photo?

Comment: @Houen Look carefully. In both associations `:class_name` is `Photo` (implicitly for `:photo`, explicitly for `:secondary_photo`). The only thing you need is to have a `photo_type` column on `photos` table. This column will not make `photos` STI, you would need a `type` column for that. The only reason you need it is that by using `has_one` you can't distinguish associations based on order, so you have to use some other indication. `photo_type` is there for that purpose only, to help `has_one` distinguish between 2 otherwise indistinguishable rows in the `photos` table.

Comment: Ah, got it. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: For anyone struggling with this solution: make sure you set `attr_accessible :photo_type` in your `Photo` model, otherwise your `Post` model won't be able to automatically populate it using `:conditions`. Had me stuck for nearly an hour there.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing since that `conditions` is deprecated in Rails 4?

Comment: @TimPetricola I think a [scope block](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-one) should do the trick.

Comment: Rails 4: `has_one :photo, -> { where photo_type: "primary_photo" }, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: @DamienRoche I tried to do as you stated, but I am not able to use `primary_model_object.polymorphic_associated_object.create`, as `interface_type` attribute I always get `primary_model` name. Is it possible to make rails correctly fill `interface_type` attribute based on where condition? Thank a lot for suggestions.

Comment: Also when I try to query with scope block it looks like:
`SELECT "generic_items".* FROM "generic_items" WHERE "generic_items"."itemable_id" = ? AND "generic_items"."itemable_type" = ? AND "generic_items"."itemable_type" = ?  [["itemable_id", 1], ["itemable_type", "Project"], ["itemable_type", "project_goals"]]`

Answer (score 27):

In **Rails 5** you have to **define attr_accessor for :attachable_id** and specify for relation **:class_name and :foreign_key** options only.
You will get ...AND attachable_type = 'SecondaryPhoto' if as: :attachable used

```
class Post
  attr_accessor :attachable_id
  has_one :photo, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :secondary_photo, -> { where attachable_type: 'SecondaryPhoto' }, class_name: "Photo", dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :attachable_id
```

Rails 4.2+

```
class Photo
   belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Post
   has_one :photo, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
   has_one :secondary_photo, -> { where attachable_type: "SecondaryPhoto"},
     class_name: Photo, foreign_key: :attachable_id,
     foreign_type: :attachable_type, dependent: :destroy
end
```

You need to provide foreign_key according ....able'ness or Rails will ask for post_id column in photo table. Attachable_type column will fills with Rails magic as `SecondaryPhoto`

Comment: in my case imageable_type is not setting accordingly what can be reason?

Comment: I have also asked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328735/imageable-type-is-not-setting-for-polymorphic-associations

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on Rails 5 & 6. Any suggestions on what might need to change?

Comment: I solved it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66952815/788798

Answer (score 12):

None of the previous answers helped me solve this problem, so I'll put this here incase anyone else runs into this. Using Rails 4.2 +.

Create the migration (assuming you have an Addresses table already):

```
class AddPolymorphicColumnsToAddress < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :addresses, :addressable_type, :string, index: true
    add_column :addresses, :addressable_id, :integer, index: true
    add_column :addresses, :addressable_scope, :string, index: true
  end
end
```

Setup your polymorphic association:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Setup the class where the association will be called from:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bill_address, -> { where(addressable_scope: :bill_address) }, as: :addressable,  class_name: "Address", dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bill_address, allow_destroy: true

  has_one :ship_address, -> { where(addressable_scope: :ship_address) }, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address", dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ship_address, allow_destroy: true
end
```

The trick is that you have to call the build method on the `Order` instance or the `scope` column won't be populated.

So this does NOT work:

```
address = {attr1: "value"... etc...}
order = Order.new(bill_address: address)
order.save!
```

However, this DOES WORK.

```
address = {attr1: "value"... etc...}
order = Order.new
order.build_bill_address(address)
order.save!
```

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on Rails 5 & 6. Any suggestions on what might need to change?

Comment: @geoboy this is still working in a large rails app that’s been moved from 4.2 to 5.0 

Xto 6.1

Comment: @geoboy just FYI, this is still working for me in a large rails app that’s been moved from 4.2 to 5.x to 6.1.

Answer (score 6):

Something like following worked for querying, but assigning from User to address didn't work

User Class

```
has_many :addresses, as: :address_holder
has_many :delivery_addresses, -> { where :address_holder_type => "UserDelivery" },
       class_name: "Address", foreign_key: "address_holder_id"
```

Address Class

```
belongs_to :address_holder, polymorphic: true
```

Comment: `foreign_key` is the key (haha) here that other answers alluded to. This works in Rails 4 for me.

Comment: Yes, when creating factories I've had to explicitly set the `address_holder_type`

Answer (score 5):

**Future reference for people checking this post**

This can be achieved using the following code...

Rails 3:

```
has_one :banner_image, conditions: { attachable_type: 'ThemeBannerAttachment' }, class_name: 'Attachment', foreign_key: 'attachable_id', dependent: :destroy
```

Rails 4:

```
has_one :banner_image, -> { where attachable_type: 'ThemeBannerAttachment'}, class_name: 'Attachment', dependent: :destroy
```

Not sure why, but in Rails 3, you need to supply a foreign_key value alongside the conditions and class_name. Do not use 'as: :attachable' as this will automatically use the calling class name when setting the polymorphic type.

*The above applies to has_many too.*

Answer (score 3):

I didn't use it, but I googled around and looked into Rails sources and I think that what you're looking for is `:foreign_type`. Try it and tell if it works :)

```
has_one :secondary_photo, :as => :attachable, :class_name => "Photo", :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_type => 'SecondaryPost'
```

I think that type in your question should be `Post` instead of `Photo` and, respectively, it would be better to use `SecondaryPost` as it assigned to `Post` model.

EDIT:

Above answer is completly wrong. `:foreign_type` is availble in polymorphic model in `belongs_to` association to specify name of the column that contains type of associated model.

As I look in Rails sources, this line sets this type for association:

```
dependent_conditions << "#{reflection.options[:as]}_type = '#{base_class.name}'" if reflection.options[:as]
```

As you can see it uses `base_class.name` to get type name. As far as I know you can do nothing with it.

So my sugestion is to add one column to Photo model, on example: `photo_type`. And set it to 0 if it is first photo, or set it to 1 if it is second photo. In your associations add `:conditions => {:photo_type => 0}` and `:conditions => {:photo_type => 1}`, respectively. I know it is not a solution you are looking for, but I can't find anything better. By the way,   maybe it would be better to just use `has_many` association?

Comment: Unfortunately Rails 2.1 doesn't have foreign_type

Comment: I think it was added around 2.3. So I think that there is no other way of doing what you want. You can try adding this feature manualy or, what is much better, upgrade your application to 2.3.5 and always stay on latest version.

Comment: I tried w/Rails 2.3.5 and it still tells me unknown key: foreign_type :(

Comment: Take a look at associations.rb valid_keys_for_has_one_association :class_name, :foreign_key, :remote, :select, :conditions, :order,
:include, :dependent, :counter_cache, :extend, :as, :readonly, :validate, :primary_key

Answer (score 2):

Your going to have to monkey patch the notion of foreign_type into has_one relationship.
This is what i did for has_many. In a new .rb file in your initializers folder i called mine add_foreign_type_support.rb
It lets you specify what your attachable_type is to be.
Example: has_many photo, :class_name => "Picture", :as => attachable, :foreign_type => 'Pic'

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class HasManyAssociation < AssociationCollection #:nodoc:
      protected
        def construct_sql
          case
            when @reflection.options[:finder_sql]
              @finder_sql = interpolate_sql(@reflection.options[:finder_sql])
           when @reflection.options[:as]
              resource_type = @reflection.options[:foreign_type].to_s.camelize || @owner.class.base_class.name.to_s
              @finder_sql =  "#{@reflection.quoted_table_name}.#{@reflection.options[:as]}_id = #{owner_quoted_id} AND "
              @finder_sql += "#{@reflection.quoted_table_name}.#{@reflection.options[:as]}_type = #{@owner.class.quote_value(resource_type)}"
              else
                @finder_sql += ")"
              end
              @finder_sql << " AND (#{conditions})" if conditions

            else
              @finder_sql = "#{@reflection.quoted_table_name}.#{@reflection.primary_key_name} = #{owner_quoted_id}"
              @finder_sql << " AND (#{conditions})" if conditions
          end

          if @reflection.options[:counter_sql]
            @counter_sql = interpolate_sql(@reflection.options[:counter_sql])
          elsif @reflection.options[:finder_sql]
            # replace the SELECT clause with COUNT(*), preserving any hints within /* ... */
            @reflection.options[:counter_sql] = @reflection.options[:finder_sql].sub(/SELECT (\/\*.*?\*\/ )?(.*)\bFROM\b/im) { "SELECT #{$1}COUNT(*) FROM" }
            @counter_sql = interpolate_sql(@reflection.options[:counter_sql])
          else
            @counter_sql = @finder_sql
          end
        end
    end
  end
end
# Add foreign_type to options list
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations # :nodoc:
     module ClassMethods
      private
        mattr_accessor :valid_keys_for_has_many_association
        @@valid_keys_for_has_many_association = [
          :class_name, :table_name, :foreign_key, :primary_key, 
          :dependent,
          :select, :conditions, :include, :order, :group, :having, :limit, :offset,
          :as, :foreign_type, :through, :source, :source_type,
          :uniq,
          :finder_sql, :counter_sql,
          :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove,
          :extend, :readonly,
          :validate, :inverse_of
        ]

    end
  end
```

Comment: This is the code I'm using with my rails 2.3.8 application. I would say step threw the logic and see if you have to make adjustments. The idea is your pass a foreign_type options params and if that exists you overload the default behavor on the select statement you might have to to_s.camelize the value if you pass it in as a :symbol

Answer (score 2):

None of these solutions seem to work on Rails 5. For some reason, it looks like the behaviour around the association conditions has changed. When assigning the related object, the conditions don't seem to be used in the insert; only when reading the association.

My solution was to override the setter method for the association:

```
has_one :photo, -> { photo_type: 'primary_photo'},
        as: 'attachable',
        dependent: :destroy

def photo=(photo)
  photo.photo_type = 'primary_photo'
  super
end
```

Comment: Nice idea, but instead of using the `photo_type` I prefer to create `photo_scope` (or in my case it was `addressable_scope`) to make the `belongs_to` call backwards compatipable.

Comment: So would you have two methods to override both primary and secondary photo? Does the insertion work then?

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late, but this might help someone so here is how I fix this (`rails 5.2`, `ruby 2.6`):

I added an `enum`, called `kind` to the model and then added the proper scope to the `has_one` association:

```rb
class Photo 
   belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
   enum kind: %i[first_photo secondary_photo]
end

class Post
   has_one :photo, -> { where(kind: :first_photo) }, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
   has_one :secondary_photo, -> { where(kind: :secondary_photo) }, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

The scope is needed because ActiveRecord can discriminate between the objects/association.

Hope the above helps!

Answer (score 1):

### For **mongoid** use this solution

Had tough times after discovering this issue but got cool solution that works

**Add to your Gemfile**

> gem 'mongoid-multiple-polymorphic'

**And this works like a charm:**

```
  class Resource

  has_one :icon, as: :assetable, class_name: 'Asset', dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
  has_one :preview, as: :assetable, class_name: 'Asset', dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a SecondaryPhoto model like:

```
class SecondaryPhoto < Photo
end
```

and then skip the :class_name from the has_one :secondary_photo?

Comment: That does seem like a workable solution - I was hoping there was a "built-in" way to do what I wanted....

Comment: I tried that - it passes Photo as the type just as if I did class_name!

Comment: How are you "attaching" the secondary photo to the Post?

In any case, I'm curious to know if klew's answer about :foreign_type works.

Answer (score 0):

```
  has_one :photo, -> { where attachable_type: "Photo" }, foreign_key: :attachable_id, class_name: Attachment.to_s, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :logo, -> { where attachable_type: "Logo" }, foreign_key: :attachable_id, class_name: Attachment.to_s, dependent: :destroy
```

when attaching:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
     attachment = user.attachments.find( id )
     user.logo = attachment
     user.save

     attachment.update( attachable_type: "Logo" )
     attachment.save
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to add a `role` field to your `Photo` model. This `role` field can store information about whether a `Photo` is a primary photo or a secondary photo. It's not ideal because it would require modifying your existing model and any related code, but it might work for your situation.

Here is an example how you can implement it:

You'd need to add a migration:

```rb
class AddRoleToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :photos, :role, :string
  end
end
```

And you'd need to add a default scope to your `Photo` model:

```rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
  scope :primary, -> { where(role: 'primary') }
  scope :secondary, -> { where(role: 'secondary') }
end
```

Your `Post` model would look like this:

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :photo, -> { primary }, :as => :attachable, :class_name => "Photo", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :secondary_photo, -> { secondary }, :as => :attachable, :class_name => "Photo", :dependent => :destroy
end
```

This will generate the correct SQL to distinguish between primary and secondary photos.

A couple of points to be aware of:

1. You need to ensure you set the `role` attribute correctly when creating `Photo` objects.
2. If you have existing `Photo` objects, you'll need to backfill the `role` attribute for them.

While this approach would require modifying the model and backfilling data, it should solve your issue. It would also avoid the need to create new Photo classes (like SecondaryPhoto), which can simplify the codebase.

Answer (score -1):

Using rails 7, I used STI to solve this problem.
This approach is simple and cleaner as I didn't have to state the `class_name:` in the association and the document type gets populated automatically.

```rb
# migration file
class CreateDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :documents, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.string :type, null: false
      t.references :entity, type: :uuid, polymorphic: true
      ...
    end
  end
end

# Document model i.e the base model
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entity, polymorphic: true
  ...
end

# Sub classes of Document
class InsuranceSticker < Document
end

class RoadWorthyCertificate < Document
end
...


# Vehicles and Drivers are entities that can hold documents
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :insurance_sticker, as: :entity, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :road_worthy_certificate, as: :entity, dependent: :destroy

  # nested
  accepts_nested_attributes_for(:insurance_sticker, :road_worthy_certificate)
  ...
end

class Driver < User
  has_one drivers_license, as: :entity, dependent: :destroy

  # nested
  accepts_nested_attributes_for(
    :drivers_license,
    :reverse_side_of_drivers_license
  )
end
```