# polymorphic model but want multiple versions of it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a polymorphic asset model but would like two different versions of it for an asset class. Something like:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, :as => :assetable, :order => 'position'
  has_many :assets :known_as => :cover_images, :as => :assetable, :order => 'position'
```

I saw this question: [Rails Polymorphic Association with multiple associations on the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494452/rails-polymorphic-association-with-multiple-associations-on-the-same-model) but when I implemented in Rails 3.1 with my models, it looked like:

```
has_many :assets, :as => :assetable, :order => 'position'
has_one :header_photo, :class_name => 'Asset', :as => 'assetable', :conditions => {:assetable_type => 'header_asset'}, :dependent => :destroy
```

Looking in console, I see:

```
SELECT `assets`.* FROM `assets` WHERE `assets`.`assetable_id` = 37 AND `assets`.`assetable_type` = 'Location' AND `assets`.`assetable_type` = 'header_asset' LIMIT 1
```

which is not what I want.

How would I do this? Is there syntax for handling this?

thx

Comment: sorry but could not understand your question properly as far as I understand you need to use assets model as polymorphic so please elaborate it properly. 

You can also find good example on polymorphic association on 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: i'm familiar with polymorphic associations hence - this is a variation on handling different ones which might be inconsistent with rails 3 which is what the previous answer addresses.