# How can I reference the same model twice and create the association in a multiple select form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, polymorphism

I have two classes (Game and Report) and want to link them with an additional attribute (default = yes or no). 
The game should then have default_reports and optional_reports.
The association is then updated by selecting the default and optional reports in a select (multiple) in the games create/edit form.

I have tried using has_many and through as well as polymorphic associations, but nothing seems to fit the use case, where the associated objects are fixed and you only want to manage associations.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_reports
  has_many :reports, :through => :game_reports
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_reports
  has_many :games, :through => :game_reports
end

class GameReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :report
end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is just the model.  the view and form to create the records is an entirely different matter.

you can always add a conditions option to has_many.  I'm assuming you're going to add default to game_reports so change your class to something like.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_reports
  has_many :reports, :through => :game_reports
  has_many :default_reports, through: :game_reports, source: :report, conditions: { game_reports: { default: true } }
end
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I was nearly that far.
I would like to not change the games controller at all, just select some reports (and send their report.id) and handle the associations automatically. There should be a rails way?!

The form field for the multiple select looks like this:
<%= f.select :required_reports, options_for_select(Report.all.map {|r| [r.name, r.id]}, @game.required_reports.map {|rr| rr.id}), {}, {:multiple => true} %>

This results in a params string like this:
{:game => {"required_reports"=>["",
 "2"]},..} 
update error:
Report(#11316) expected, got String(#11318)

Comment: nearly there:
using <%= f.select :default_report_ids, Report.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %> right now and the maybe last problem is, that the GameReport validation fails because the required (default oroptional) boolean value is not set. Do I have to manually insert that into the params hash or is there a better way to add this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4.2+, use a Polymorphic association with scope and specify the **foreign_key** and **foreign_type** options.

```
class GameReport
   belongs_to :report, :polymorphic => true
end

class Game
   has_many :game_reports, :as => :report, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :reports, -> { where attachable_type: "GameReport"},
     class_name: GameReport, foreign_key: :game_report_id,
     foreign_type: :game_report_type, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Other approachs:

[Rails Polymorphic Association with multiple associations on the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494452/rails-polymorphic-association-with-multiple-associations-on-the-same-model)