# Multi has_many relations to polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have three models Agreement, Service and Price.

```
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices, as: :priceable
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices, as: :priceable
end

class Price  < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :price_currency, :priceable_id, :priceable_type
  belongs_to :priceable, polymorphic: true
end
```

But I have two price types in service customer_price and agency_price. Agreement hasn't price type. I want to model something like below. How it is possible?

```
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices, as: :priceable
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_prices, as: :priceable # I think I should write something here
  has_many :agency_prices, as: :priceable   # I think I should write something here
end

class Price  < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :price_currency, :priceable_id, :priceable_type
  belongs_to :priceable, polymorphic: true
end
```

What is best approach? May be I should make two price model like AgreementPrice and ServicePrice. Best Regards.

Comment: Why do you think that your approach doesn't work?

Comment: Because prices.priceable_type stores only class name (Service or Agreement) not price type (customer_price or agency_price).

Comment: So this means that you want to access customer_price from the Price object and not only from the Service object (in which case your argument is not problematic)

Comment: has_many :customer_price, as: :priceable, :conditions => {: priceable_type => 'customer_price'} and has_many : agency_price, as: :priceable, :conditions => {: priceable_type => 'agency_price'} will solve my problem. Question is duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494452/rails-polymorphic-association-with-multiple-associations-on-the-same-model Thanks you for your answer.

Comment: `has_many :price` is supposed to be `has_many :prices` . 'Plural'.

Answer (score 0):

Making two models wouldn't help you actually.

I think you only need to set a specific foreign_key to your relations.

```
has_many :customer_price, as: :priceable, :foreign_key => customer_price_id
has_many :agency_price, as: :priceable, :foreign_key => agency_price_id
```

Those two fields must be added in your schema.

Comment: Price model is polymorphic. If I add foreign_keys at price table, what is the different of has_many relation?