# Rails model with two polymorphic has_many through: associations for object tagging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, tagging

My schema has `Articles` and `Journals` that can be tagged with `Tags`. This requires a `has_many through:` association with a polymorphic relationship to my `Tagging` join table.

Okay, that's the easy and well documented part.

My problem is that `Articles` can have both primary-tags and sub-tags. The primary tags are what I'm most interested in, but my model also needs to keep track of these sub tags. Sub tags are simply labels describing the `Article` that are of lesser importance, but come from the same global pool of `Tags`. (in fact, one `Article`'s primary-tag may be another's sub-tag).

Achieving this requires the `Article` model to have two associations to the `Tagging` model and two `has_many through:` associations to `Tags` (i.e. #tags & #sub-tags)

This is what I have so far, which while valid does not keep primary-tags and sub-tags separate.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

  has_many :sub_taggings, as: :taggable, class_name: 'Tagging',
           source_type: 'article_sub'
  has_many :sub_tags, through: :sub_taggings, class_name: 'Tag', source: :tag
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  #  id            :integer
  #  taggable_id   :integer
  #  taggable_type :string(255)
  #  tag_id        :integer
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
end
```

I know that somewhere in there I need to find the right combination of `source` and `source_type` but I can't work it out.

For completeness here is my `article_spec.rb` that I'm using to test this — currently failing on "the incorrect tags".

```
describe "referencing tags" do
  before do
    @article.tags << Tag.find_or_create_by_name("test")
    @article.tags << Tag.find_or_create_by_name("abd")
    @article.sub_tags << Tag.find_or_create_by_name("test2")
    @article.sub_tags << Tag.find_or_create_by_name("abd")
  end

  describe "the correct tags" do
    its(:tags) { should include Tag.find_by_name("test") }
    its(:tags) { should include Tag.find_by_name("abd") }
    its(:sub_tags) { should include Tag.find_by_name("abd") }
    its(:sub_tags) { should include Tag.find_by_name("test2") }
  end

  describe "the incorrect tags" do
    its(:tags) { should_not include Tag.find_by_name("test2") }
    its(:sub_tags) { should_not include Tag.find_by_name("test") }
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help on achieving this. The main problem is I cannot work out how to tell Rails the source_type to use for the sub_tags association in Articles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hmmm... Silence again...? What gives SO? Hello...? Bueller?

**Never fear, here's the answer:**

After looking into [Single Table Inheritance](http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails) (*not* the answer, but an interesting technique for other slightly-related problems), I stumbled across a SO question regarding multiple-references to a polymorphic association on the same model. (Thank you hakunin for your [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078286/59195), +1.)

Basically we need to explicitly define the contents of the `taggable_type` column in the `Taggings` table for the `sub_taggings` association, but not with `source` or `source_type`, instead with `:conditions`.

The `Article` model shown below now passes all the tests:

```
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
   has_many :tags, through: :taggings, uniq: true, dependent: :destroy

   has_many :sub_taggings, as: :taggable, class_name: 'Tagging',
             conditions: {taggable_type: 'article_sub_tag'},
             dependent: :destroy
   has_many :sub_tags, through: :sub_taggings, class_name: 'Tag',
             source: :tag, uniq: true
 end
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the correct `Tag` model that produces functional reverse polymorphic associations on Tags. The reverse association (ie. Tag.articles and Tag.sub_tagged_articles) passes tests.

```
 class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles, through: :taggings, source: :taggable,
             source_type: "Article"
   has_many :sub_tagged_articles, through: :taggings, source: :taggable,
             source_type: "Article_sub_tag", class_name: "Article"
 end
```

I have also extended and successfully tested the schema to allow tagging & sub_tagging of other models using the same Tag model and Tagging join table. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Came here in search for an answer to a different question but such a thoroughly answered question surely deserves an upvote (even moreso if you solved it on your own).

Comment: Thanks Michael / doubly appreciated during these crazy times! The solution is still going strong in production 7+ years later.