# imageable type is not setting for polymorphic associations

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models in my rails 4.2 application

```
class LandingPage < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :section2_photo, -> { where imageable_type: "Section2Photo"},
    class_name: Image, foreign_key: :imageable_id, foreign_type: :imageable_type, dependent: :destroy, as: :imageable

  has_one :section3_photo, -> { where imageable_type: "Section3Photo"},
    class_name: Image, foreign_key: :imageable_id, foreign_type: :imageable_type, dependent: :destroy, as: :imageable
end
```

and

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I have problem with imageable_type which is not getting set accordingly for example if I do this in console

```
landingpage = LandingPage.first
image = landingpage.build_section2_photo
```

but when I do

```
image.imageable_type
```

i get

```
"LandingPage"
```

rather than

```
"Section2Photo"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just posting for others I removed

```
as: :imageable
```

and working fine now