# Multiple polymorphic associations work with rails 4 not rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The following code works perfectly fine with rails 4.2.7, but with rails 5+ it throws a **NameError initialized constant 'BonesReqPhoto'**

model l2_requirement.rb

```
has_one :bones_req_photo, -> { where requireable_type: "BonesReqPhoto" }, 
  class_name: "ReqPhoto", foreign_key: :requireable_id, 
  foreign_type: :requireable_type
has_one :bubbling_req_photo, -> { where requireable_type: "BubblingReqPhoto" }, 
  class_name: "ReqPhoto", foreign_key: :requireable_id, 
  foreign_type: :requireable_type
```

model req_photo.rb

```
belongs_to :requireable, polymorphic: true
```

The model uses a polymorphic association multiple times. The where constraint is used to differentiate between the two.

I used this answer to figure out how to solve this problem for rails 4, but was frustrated to no avail trying to get this to work for rails 5: [imageable type is not setting for polymorphic associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328735/imageable-type-is-not-setting-for-polymorphic-associations)

What is the proper way to do this in rails 5?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I misunderstood the original guide. I was trying to replace the requireable_type, which caused much headache later.

The correct answer is to **add a new column**. I chose req_type

```
has_one :bones_req_photo, -> { where req_type: "BonesReqPhoto" }, 
  class_name: "ReqPhoto", as: :requireable
has_one :bubbling_req_photo, -> { where req_type: "BubblingReqPhoto" }, 
  class_name: "ReqPhoto", as: :requireable
```